# jQuery UI dialog: window appears at the right of the screen in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

anybody else had this problem, do you know how to fix this ?

my code:

```
var currentFormconfirm;
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 220,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    currentFormconfirm.submit();
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $(".confirm").click(function () {
            currentFormconfirm = $(this).closest('form');
            $("#dialog-confirm-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not an aswer, but: Does it happen with the demo here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ ? If so, I'd check the bug tracker (http://dev.jqueryui.com/). If not, at least you know it's something you can fix...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder no, it doesn't happen with the demo

Comment: @Omu - What you have works, must be your markup/CSS, do you have a link we can see?

Comment: Can we see the pertinent HTML as well?

Comment: It must be something else in the markup, that code is fine: http://jsbin.com/anozi5 Your best bet is to create a *minimalist failing test case* and post it to something like JSBin.com or jsFiddle.net, that sort of thing. Two reasons for this: 1. About 90% of the time, in the process of doing it, you figure out what's wrong. 2. If you don't, you can post the code here and people like Nick, James, and myself will be happy to help out.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder ok, should I delete this question, or just leave it for the moment

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry I was using an older version of jqueryui.css from google apis, this was my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have this problem. My solution:

```
    $('#dlg') 
    .dialog('open')            
    .dialog({position:'center'});  //UI Dialog positioning error
```

Comment: try using the latest version of jquery.js and .css

Answer (score 2):

fix it, by using the **latest version** of `Jquery.js` and `.css`